# using genfromtxt to split data

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

With Python, I am using `genfromtxt` (from numpy) to read in a text file into an array:

```
y = np.genfromtxt("1400list.txt", dtype=[('mystring','S20'),('myfloat','float')])
```

Which works okay, except it doesn't seem to read my 2 columns into a 2D array. I am getting:

`[('string001', 123.0),('string002', 456.0),('string002', 789.0)]`

But I *think* would like:

`[['string001', 123.0],['string002', 456.0],['string002', 789.0]]`

I basically want each piece of information as a separate element that I can then manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

What `genfromtxt` returns is called a *structured array*.  It gives a **1d array of tuples**, each tuple has the `dtype` that you specified.

These are actually very useful once you learn how to use them.  You cannot have a 2d array with floats and strings, but with a structured array, you can!

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO
s = """string001 123
       string002 456
       string002 789"""
f = StringIO(s)
y = np.genfromtxt(f, dtype=[('mystring', 'S20'), ('myfloat', float)])
```

Which is what you have so far.  Now you can access `y` in the following fashion.  You can use a *field name* to get a column as a 1d array:

```
>>> y['mystring']
array(['string001', 'string002', 'string002'], 
  dtype='|S20')

>>> y['myfloat']
array([ 123.,  456.,  789.])
```

Note that `y['myfloat']` gives `float`s because of the `dtype` argument, even though in the file they are `int`s.

Or, you can use an integer to get a row as a `tuple` with the given `dtype`:

```
>>> y[1]
('string002', 456.0)
```

If you are doing a lot of manipulation of data structures like this, you might want to look into [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)