# Extract columns using "genfromtxt"

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pandas, tuples

I've already read these 2 questions before asking this one (**[q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238355/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-unpack-tuples)** and **[q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291665/using-genfromtxt-to-split-data)**) but I haven't found any satisfying answer

I need to extract two columns from a 2D-array without using *pandas* or *loadtxt*, but with **genfromtxt**

For now, what I did is:

```
X = np.genfromtxt('File1.csv', 
                    delimiter='\t', 
                    skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, 
                    names=True , usecols=("Time") )

Y = np.genfromtxt('File1.csv', 
                    delimiter='\t', 
                    skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, 
                    names=True , usecols=("Profit") )
```

then, using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) I plot Y vs X, result is perfect

Now, I was thinking that I should do it the "right" way and avoid reading twice the array.
So I tried the **unpack** feature:

```
 X, Y = np.genfromtxt('File1.csv', 
                    delimiter='\t', 
                    skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, 
                    names=True , usecols=("Time", "Profit"), unpack=True )
```

I get the message: *too many values to unpack*

Now if I write the previous command with one vector for the output (say Z) without unpacking, the vector Z will contain a tuple **that cannot be plotted directly**.

Any solution to this simple-looking problem ?

Comment: Did you try using column numbers in `usecols`?

Comment: I did, but I'd rather use the names from the header since the position of these columns change between files

Comment: Sorry I mean, do you experience the problem if you use numbers in usecols?

Comment: I tried it now, same error message is displayed

Comment: You can't unpack a structured array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have more than one named field, you will have a [1-d structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), like so:

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('File1.csv', delimiter='\t', names=True, usecols=("Time", "Profit"))
array([(0.0, 1.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0)], 
      dtype=[('Time', '<f8'), ('Profit', '<f8')])
```

You can't unpack a 1d structured array, since all that `unpack=True` does is to transpose your array so that columns vary along the first axis, and the transpose of a 1d array is itself.  Thus, you get the same result with `unpack`:

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('File1.csv', delimiter='\t', names=True, usecols=("Time", "Profit"), unpack=True)
array([(0.0, 1.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0)], 
      dtype=[('Time', '<f8'), ('Profit', '<f8')])
```

Even if you use numbers in your `usecols` argument as @Roberto suggests, you still have the problem because using `names=True` gives you a structured array if you have more than one field (which is why you didn't notice it with your first attempt).

If you save this as `Z`, you can plot it like

```
plt.plot(Z['Time'], Z['Profit'])
```

or you can split it as you originally asked:

```
X, Y = Z['Time'], Z['Profit']
```

Comment: Minor, pedantic, semantic quibble: *in general*, structured arrays can be n-dimensional, so saying "*a* structured array is actually 1d" is perhaps a bit misleading.  The structured array *returned by `genfromtxt`* is 1-d.

Comment: Thanks @Warren, clarified.